# Brew installed Elasticsearch 7.9.2 failing on macOS

Tags: macos, elasticsearch

My [brew installed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/brew.html) `elasticsearch-full` started failing with error:

```sh
Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
```

macOS 10.15.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be default configuration files in `/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch`.

I suggest to backup your current configuration files, replace it with the defaults (which also should be up2date) and apply your special configuration if required.

```sh
cd /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch
cp elasticsearch.yml elasticsearch.yml.bck
cp elasticsearch.yml.default elasticsearch.yml
cp jvm.options jvm.options.bck
cp jvm.options.default jvm.options
cp log4j2.properties log4j2.properties.bck
cp log4j2.properties.default log4j2.properties
```

```sh
eddie[elasticsearch]$ ls -la
total 112
drwxr-xr-x  12 eddie  admin    384 Dec  7 12:18 .
drwxrwxr-x  39 eddie  admin   1248 Dec  6 15:22 ..
-rw-rw----   1 eddie  admin    199 Oct 27 14:16 elasticsearch.keystore
-rw-r-----   1 eddie  admin   2872 Dec  7 12:18 elasticsearch.yml
-rw-r-----   1 eddie  admin   2872 Dec  6 15:22 elasticsearch.yml.default
-rw-r-----   1 eddie  admin   3058 Dec  7 12:18 elasticsearch.yml.bck
-rw-r-----   1 eddie  admin   2357 Dec  7 12:17 jvm.options
-rw-r-----   1 eddie  admin   2357 Dec  6 15:22 jvm.options.default
-rw-r-----   1 eddie  admin   2892 Dec  7 12:17 jvm.options.bck
-rw-r-----   1 eddie  admin  11021 Dec  7 12:18 log4j2.properties
-rw-r-----   1 eddie  admin  11021 Dec  6 15:22 log4j2.properties.default
-rw-r-----   1 eddie  admin   3992 Dec  7 12:18 log4j2.properties.bck
```

Answer (score 13):

My config ended up having some old settings, so I had to comment out the lines under `GC configuration`:

```sh
# /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options

## GC configuration
#-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
#-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
#-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
```

Comment: This did it for me, Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me too, and then I hit a new snag on the relative path for the GC log files which was resolved in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479986/elasticsearch-7-3-homebrew