# Elasticsearch 6.x warning cannot open file logs/gc.log

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I had downgraded to Elasticsearch 6.X (from 7.x) using Homebrew and started to get a warning.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file logs/gc.log due to No such file or directory
```

How do you fix it?

[I've looked at a similar error on Elasticsearch 8 which gives an error but the answer does not resolve this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479986/elasticsearch-7-3-upgrade-with-homebrew)

The differences are:

- different Elasticsearch version 6.X not 7.x
- warning not an error
- I am using JDK 8 not 9.

Answer (score 2):

### Elasticsearch 6.X

Solution:

```
#
# /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options
#  - directories might be specific for Homebrew installation
#

## JDK 8 GC logging

...
# Before
8:-Xloggc:logs/gc.log
# After
8:-Xloggc:/usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log
...
```

Comment: If you are using Java 9+, you need to update this line the same way:

```# JDK 9+ GC logging
9-:-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m```